# Why are results of my media query applied in CSS files visible only in browser inspector?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am using Google Chrome and in my CSS (SCSS) files I applied a media query integrated into a mixin that looks like this:

```
@mixin render-d {
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px), screen and (min-width: 481px) and (orientation: portrait), screen and (orientation: landscape), print {
        @content;
    }
};
```

The mixin with media query above allows me to do for example this:

```
.column {
    width: 100%;

    @include render-d {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

What I wanted to achieve with my media query in the example above (desired effect):

- if min-width greater than 768px then apply `width: 50%`
- if min-width greater than 481px then apply `width: 50%` only if the orientation is portrait
- on any device if the orientation is landscape then apply `width: 50%`
- if print then apply `width: 50%`
- anything else will apply `width: 100%`

My problem:

The desired effect is visible **ONLY** when I use Google Chrome inspector (developer tool) and a built-in device toolbar (where you can test any device and responsitivity). When I escape Chrome developer tool and try to resize the browser window to make is more narrow, it DOES NOT WORK.

What I am doing wrong?

Important NOTE: I also had to add this line into my HTML file to make it work only in Google Chrome inspector though:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: You should provide an [mcve]. Include some HTML. Include CSS instead of SASS. Make a live demo with the Stack Snippet feature.

Comment: Your code should work. While debugging this, the first step is to find out whether the problem lies with how SASS is converted to CSS or if it has to do with how CSS is interpreted by browser. Technically, in CSS, prior code can render perfectly valid code invalid. So, without a working, testable example, nobody can help you much, except people who can actually use your machine. Note you can use SASS in both jsFiddle and codepen.